# Why can't you see textboxes in Windows mobile standard?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I am looking at windows mobile standard(non touch screen). I dragged in some text boxes and when I run it you don't see them. You only see them if you go if the arrows and move them around.

I find that kinda stupid how would I person know where a text box is?

Also does anyone actually know how many ppl still use no touch screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has no border and is the same color as your Form.  That would explain why you don't see it.  Labels and color differences often are useful for helping users know where a control is.

And as to the second question, I use a non-touch device (Dash 3G), so there are still some people that do.

Comment: How do I show a border. I thought about that but I can't find the border option.